# C++ code to emulate virtually mapped network drive under Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Here is the situation:

I have a RESTful web service which when queried returns a list of virtual files (file-name, size, last modified, creation date and an id). It is also possible to get the binary content data of any file using its id from the same web service.

What I want to do:

I want to write a piece of C++ code which convinces the operating system (Windows XP, vista or 7) that there exists a mapped network drive (for ex: Z) such that when the user types (Z:\) in windows explorer the list of virtual files (which is returned from the web service) is displayed. Also when double clicking on a file icon in the explorer view, the piece of C++ code should retrieve the binary data form the web service and present it to the OS as the legitimate file content.

In other words, the user (and the OS for that matter) shouldn't be able to tell the difference between Z and any other ordinary drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Write a WebDAV wrapper and use Web Folders?

Comment: @ChrisV: Does Web Folders make the files appear under a drive letter, or only with URL syntax?

Comment: Here is some info for mounting on XP and Vista.  I suspect (but don't know) that the Vista instructions will work for Windows: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html I have to agree that this seems like the best way to go.  Writing a Windows file system is not easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called "userspace file system". You can create one, for example, on top of [Dokan library](http://dokan-dev.net/en/).

Answer (score 1):

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/fuse-nt.pdf

A couple more listed on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace#External_links)

Answer (score 1):

Our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) is what you are looking for.

Callback File System lets you map generic data (such as the ones retrieved from the remote web service) to the drive letter.

Comment: @user698585 You asked for a solution, which we have. If you prefer free stuff, that's ok, yet you should have mentioned this in your question.

Comment: My apologies, you are right that it should have been mentioned in the question.